# Python XML to CSV - problem with property

Tags: python, xml, loops, csv

Today i try to convert simple xml to csv file.
XML:

```
<cars>
<car>
<id>1234</id>
<name>Name Of Car</name>
<description>Nice Car! </description>
<image>http://www.images.com</image>
<cost>432</cost>
<cat>roadster</cat>
<property name="Url">someurl</property>
<property name="Color">red</property>
<property name="Produce">fiat</property>
<property name="SystemID">15</property>
</car>
</cars>
```

```
tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
Resident_data = open('ResidentData.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig')
csvwriter = csv.writer(Resident_data)
resident_head = []
count = 0
start = 0
for member in root.findall('car'):
    offers = []
    if count == 0:
        resident_head.append("ID")
        resident_head.append("NAME")
        resident_head.append("DESC")
        resident_head.append("IMG")
        resident_head.append("PRICE")
        resident_head.append("TYPE")
        resident_head.append("URL")
        resident_head.append("COLOR")
        resident_head.append("PRODUCE")
        resident_head.append("SYSID")
        
        csvwriter.writerow(resident_head)
        count = count + 1

    ID = member.find('id').text
    offers.append(ID)
    NAME = member.find('name').text
    offers.append(NAME)
    DESC = member.find('description').text
    offers.append(DESC)
    IMG = member.find('image').text
    offers.append(IMG)
    PRICE = member.find('cost').text
    offers.append(PRICE)
    CAT = member.find('cat').text
    offers.append(CAT)
    
    csvwriter.writerow(offers)
    start = start + 1
    print(start)

Resident_data.close()
```

Output:

| ID | NAME | DESC | IMG | PRICE | TYPE | URL | COLOR | PRODUCE | SYSID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Name Of car | Nice Car! | http:.. | 432 | roadster |  |  |  |  |

All working good but for this moment, but i don't know how to loop last columns, because here is `<property name="x">`. Also sometimes SYSID or COLOR is none (empty in system)

Ps. In preview my table looks ok...

Thanks! :)

Comment: Either get with xpath PRODUCT[@name=‘COLOR´]

Comment: You can also create an xsl file that make the xml conversion and use it in python.

Comment: There're 2 answers on your question. You can choose one which you find more helpful and [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below (The code builds the csv headers dynamically based on the xml data). The code handle missing `property` as well. It assumes a properties are in the **first** car.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
from typing import NamedTuple



xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cars>
   <car>
      <id>1234</id>
      <name>Name Of Car</name>
      <description>Nice Car!</description>
      <image>http://www.images.com</image>
      <cost>432</cost>
      <cat>roadster</cat>
      <property name="Url">someurl</property>
      <property name="Color">red</property>
      <property name="Produce">fiat</property>
      <property name="SystemID">15</property>
   </car>
   <car>
      <id>1235</id>
      <name>Name Of Car1</name>
      <description>Nice Car!1</description>
      <image>http://www.images.com</image>
      <cost>435</cost>
      <cat>roadster45</cat>
      <property name="Url">someurl34</property>
      <!-- property name="Color">green</property -->
      <property name="Produce">nest</property>
      <property name="SystemID">45</property>
   </car>
</cars>'''

class EntryProp(NamedTuple):
  name:str
  is_prop: bool

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
meta = []
data = []
for idx,car in enumerate(root.findall('.//car')):
  if idx == 0:
    for p in list(car):
      if p.tag != 'property':
        meta.append(EntryProp(p.tag,False))
      else:
        meta.append(EntryProp(p.attrib['name'],True))
        
  values = []
  for entry in meta:
    if entry.is_prop:
      ele = car.find(f'property[@name="{entry.name}"]')
      if ele is None:
        values.append('')
      else:
        values.append(ele.text)
    else:
      values.append(car.find(entry.name).text)
  data.append(values)
      

with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow([p.name.upper() for p in meta])
    for entry in data:
      wr.writerow(entry)
```

out.csv

```
ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,IMAGE,COST,CAT,URL,COLOR,PRODUCE,SYSTEMID
1234,Name Of Car,Nice Car!,http://www.images.com,432,roadster,someurl,red,fiat,15
1235,Name Of Car1,Nice Car!1,http://www.images.com,435,roadster45,someurl34,,nest,45
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working nice, but i have one question. Sometimes i dont have color or url (empty) and my results in the table lose space, in a sense, they add up to a place that should be empty
`ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,IMAGE,COST,CAT,URL,COLOR,PRODUCE,SYSTEMID`
now is:
`1234,Name Of Car,Nice Car!,images.com,432,roadster,fiat,15`
should be
`1234,Name Of Car,Nice Car!,images.com,432,roadster,blank,blank,fiat,15`

Comment: @Karmay Code was modified in order to support missing properties.

Comment: @balderman, `EntryProp` should be [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), subclassing `namedtuple` is not a common way.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I do not agree with you. I do not subclass `namedtuple`. I subclass `NamedTuple` which was designed for extending. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/typing-namedtuple-improved-namedtuples/

Comment: @Karmay Are the properties of  `car` is a closed set or there are dynamic fields?

Comment: @balderman, you can do this, but for this particular reason better fits `dataclass`.

Answer (score 2):

If there's possible extra fields or some fields missing, it could be a good option to use [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter). I your example `<cars>` node *(which is root node)* contains only `<car>` child nodes, so we can just iterate over root node. If your real XML is more complex, you can use [`.iterfind()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.iterfind) with simple `.//car` XPath expression.

**Code:**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from csv import DictWriter

xml = ...
root = ET.fromstring(xml)  # replace with initialization from file (if needed)

with open("result.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = None
    for car_node in root:
        car = {node.get("name") or node.tag: node.text for node in car_node}
        if not writer:
            writer = DictWriter(f, car, extrasaction="ignore")
            writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow(car)
```

---

**Upd.** If you're not sure in parameters which could be in child nodes, you can collect all data as dictionaries into [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#chainmap-objects) and write it after. All missing values will be replaced by value passed to `restval` argument of `DictWriter` contructor *(default value is empty string)*:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from csv import DictWriter
from collections import ChainMap

xml = ...
root = ET.fromstring(xml)

cars = ChainMap()
for car_node in root:  # root.iterfind(".//car")
    car = {node.get("name") or node.tag: node.text for node in car_node}
    cars = cars.new_child(car)

with open("result.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = DictWriter(f, cars)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(cars.maps[:-1])  # last is an empty dict
```